# Separating Sandcastle Assembly Documentation into Multiple Navigation TOCs

Tags: sandcastle, shfb

I maintain multiple .NET assemblies each with their own independent release cycles. It is intended that I produce a single help website for all of these assemblies, but also keep both conceptual content and namespace documentation separated into distinct groups.

Here is an simplified structure of what I hope to accomplish:

`Overview
Library A
--Overview
--Release notes
--**Library A generated Namespace/Assembly documentation**
Library B
--Overview
--Release notes
--**Library B generated Namespace/Assembly documentation**
Library C
--Overview
--Release notes
--**Library C generated Namespace/Assembly documentation**`

As it stands now, this is all I've been able to successfully produce:

`Overview
Library A
--Overview
--Release notes
Library B
--Overview
--Release notes
Library C
--Overview
--Release notes
**Library A, B, and C generated Namespace/Assembly documentation**`

I already have a custom presentation style (based on the existing VS2013) so customization of the presentation layer is an option. I'm also not against writing a custom component/plugin but have thus far been unable to understand how to alter the default behavior.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and posing this question directly to the head developer of Sandcastle, there is no easy solution.

The full dialog can be found [on the project website](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/305).

In short, my best recourse is the develop a separate help website for each assembly library and link to them from the parent website. A shared token file can be helpful to maintain the back-reference paths in a single place and inject them into the content.